# Looping a parser

Tags: c, parsing, strstr

I'd like to know how I can loop a parser I did. There are several  in the text file I have and I don't know what to do. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

int parse(char **argv)
{
    /* code that converts a text file to a string called file_contents */

    char *target = NULL;
    char *target2 = NULL;
    char *start, *end;

    const char *tag1 = "<item>";
    const char *tag2 = "</item>";

    if(start = strstr(file_contents, tag1))
    {
        start += strlen(tag1);
        if(end = strstr(start, tag2))
        {
            target = (char *)malloc(end-start+1);
            memcpy(target, start, end-start);
            target[end - start] = '\0';
        }

        const char *tag3 = "<title>";
        const char *tag4 = "</title>";

        if(start = strstr(target, tag3))
        {
            start += strlen(tag3);
            if(end = strstr(start, tag4))
            {
                target2 = (char *)malloc(end-start+1);
                memcpy(target2, start, end-start);
                target2[end-start] = '\0';
                printf("%s\n", target2);
            }
        }

        /* same code for other tags */

        }
    }

    free(target);

    return 2;
}
```

A sample of a text is this.

```
<item>
    <title>blah blah</title>
    <otherTags>blah blah</otherTags>
</item>    <item>
    <title>blah blah</title>
    <otherTags>blah blah</otherTags>
</item>    <item>
    <title>blah blah</title>
    <otherTags>blah blah</otherTags>
</item>
```

My code only parses the first item. I am a newbie so guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Well, for one, your title says "Looping". That will involve in nearly all cases... a *loop*. Try one?

Comment: I don't know where to put it :( And also the condition.

Comment: I hope for your own sake that you're doing the parser as a learning exercise, as parsers for markup-files like yours exists already. Your input is nothing more than simplified XML which means that just about any XML parser should be able to handle it.

Comment: It's a learning exercise and right now I'm lost.

Comment: "I am a newbie so guide me." Not a good phrasing haha. Figure out where you would want to stop looping, and then keep looping through the remaining string until you hit that! I would also highly suggest you look into making recursive parser, it will be much easier to deal with and work much more generally!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need to do is change your `if` to a `while`, and just keep the pointers moving through the string as you go. I believe changing

```
if(start = strstr(file_contents, tag1))
```

to

```
start = file_contents;
while(start = strstr(start, tag1))
```

would get you the desired behavior (assuming the rest of the code works). It would just continue to loop through as long as you are still getting a non-NULL return from strstr on the remaining string (starting from `start`).

As I mentioned in my comment, I would also recommend you look into recursive parsing if you're up for it; it seems like it would be great for your case (*disclaimer: I am not a parser expert*). Other than that, your code looks good, especially for a self-proclaimed newbie!

---

Edit: It seems that your code needs a bit of restructuring, at least to get it to loop the way I'm suggesting. You should avoid copying strings, and just walk through it in a "nested" way. Just rearranging in and around your if statement

```
//These really should be static or #define'd, but that's another post
const char *tag1 = "<item>";
const char *tag2 = "</item>";
const char *tag3 = "<title>";
const char *tag4 = "</title>";

if(start = strstr(file_contents, tag1))
{
    start += strlen(tag1);
    if(start = strstr(target, tag3))
    {
        start += strlen(tag3);
        if(end = strstr(start, tag4))
        {
            target2 = (char *)malloc(end-start+1);
            memcpy(target2, start, end-start);
            target2[end-start] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", target2); //Replacing this with fwrite would be faster
                                     //with no malloc, but another post
            free(target2); //Don't want to leak!
        } //else, maybe return error code
    }

    /* same code for other tags */

    start = strstr(start, tag2); //Find end of <item>
    start += strlen(tag2);   //Goto remaining string
}
```

If that works, then the change I mentioned earlier should loop through properly. If you want to stick with your way, you'll need some other way of keeping track of where the remainder of your string is (the `strcpy` you mentioned in the comments might work, but that would add a lot of overhead).

Comment: It became an infinite loop. Should I copy `end` into `file_contents` ? Or is that a bad idea? I'm thinking of putting `strcpy(file_contents, end);`...

Comment: I was a bit mistaken about how you were walking through the input. It looks like you're finding the `<item>` and `</item>` tags, copying over whatever's between them, and then looking for your embedded tags in your new copy. Not only does that mean my code was wrong, but I don't know that that's a good strategy here. It seems to me that you should find the `<item>` tag, use that as a start point to find your embedded tag, then find your embedded close flag (printing out what's between them), and THEN find your `</item>` tag; all of this within your file string (using `start` to keep track)

Comment: @estudyante In direct response to your question about `strcpy`, it *would* work, but it would give you awfully bad performance. String copying like that can take a lot of time, especially if you have a very long file string. It's usually much faster and less error prone to use one string and just keep pointers into the correct place into it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I manage to make my code work using your first advice. :DD